# passing '&' in return function of add_filter

Tags: plugins, filters

I have below line in my return function of `add_filter` in wordpress.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'my_drama_func'); 
function my_drama_func () {
    return "function getthrough() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'url='+url+'&un=0&pretty=1&mega=0&click=true',
            beforeSend: function(b) {..snip..},
            error: function(e) {},
            success: function(s) {}
        });
    }";
}
```

but in content page of view source, it is available as :-

```
jQuery.ajax({
    ....ajax rest code...
    //Below line is giving trouble. :(
    data: 'url='+url+'&#038;un=0&#038;pretty=1&#038;mega=0&#038;click=true',
    ...ajax rest code..
});
```

But my requirement is to pass it as it is with '&' and not any special character of html.

How can this be achived.

Thanks

Comment: You need to escape the characters, but this seems to be a JavaScript question not related to WordPress.

Comment: I am adding this code in `return` of `add_filter`.

Comment: Filter doesn't output information into page source. What actually does in your case?

Comment: I am writing ajax function in return function of add_filter

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you are returning jQuery through PHP without script tag, so you should at the least be using this:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'my_drama_func'); 
function my_drama_func () {
    return "<script>function getthrough() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'url='+url+'&un=0&pretty=1&mega=0&click=true',
            beforeSend: function(b) {..snip..},
            error: function(e) {},
            success: function(s) {}
        });
    }</script>";
}
```

I hope you understand by using the filter on `the_content` and not returning the original content, you are making it so any post will not show the actual content anymore, only your jQuery.  If you just want the jQuery appended to the content you should at least append jQuery to original content:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'my_drama_func'); 
function my_drama_func ( $content ) {
    $append_jquery = "<script>function getthrough() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'url='+url+'&un=0&pretty=1&mega=0&click=true',
            beforeSend: function(b) {..snip..},
            error: function(e) {},
            success: function(s) {}
        });
    }</script>";

    return $content . $append_jquery;
}
```

You can also use PHP to output the url string like so:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'my_drama_func'); 
function my_drama_func ( $content ) {
    $url_args = "&un=0&pretty=1&mega=0&click=true";
    $append_jquery = "<script>function getthrough() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'url='+url+'" . $url_args . "',
            beforeSend: function(b) {..snip..},
            error: function(e) {},
            success: function(s) {}
        });
    }</script>";

    return $content . $append_jquery;
}
```

But this is just a fix I can give based on the limited details you have provided.  What are you actually trying to do?  This may (and probably isn't) the right way to do this, but it *should* work

Comment: i am trying to pass javascript code via return function of wordpress.

Comment: Provide us a paste of your PHP code surrounding this and how you're inserting it.  You can use a site like pastebin.com or even better, http://wpbin.io

Comment: I cannot paste complete code here, but i have updated look alike code in my post.

Comment: Which is why I gave you a link to a site to paste the code at ( http://wpbin.io ) ... I updated my response

Comment: `This may (and probably isn't) the right way to do this, but it should work`, i need to insert my jquery ajax function in contet, I am writing small plugin for my voting function in content.